# Markdown tables not displayed on a github .md page

Tags: github, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I have a markdown page that uses table layout, and it shows correctly as table in a VS Code markdown preview plugin, but when I check it into GitHub, it doesn't display the tables correctly but rather displays the table markdown. This is the page: https://github.com/path-foundation/path-protocol/blob/docs/docs/api.md

Markdown:

```
Inputs
| type|name |description |
|----|---|---|
| *address* | _user | address of certificate owner |
| *bytes32* | _hash | sha256 hash of the certificate text |
```

This shows on the page when viewed in github:

```
Inputs | type | name | description | | ---- | --- | --- | | address | _user | address of certificate owner | | bytes32 | _hash | sha256 hash of the certificate text |
```

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Insert an empty line before the table (after "Inputs"):

```
Inputs

| type|name |description |
|----|---|---|
| *address* | _user | address of certificate owner |
| *bytes32* | _hash | sha256 hash of the certificate text |
```

And it will be rendered correctly:

[image]